# Is jthread::request_stop signal-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals

The man page on signal-safety gives a long list of functions that can be called from a signal handler, but provides no clear rule how it can be determined that a particular function is signal-safe.

Right now I'm interested in `jthread::request_stop`, since I want to gracefully terminate my threads on SIGINT. But I wonder if there is some "rule of thumb" to determine whether some specific function can or cannot be called.

Comment: Does [Signal handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal#Signal_handler) help you (about 2 pages of conditional description)?

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, I saw this page. The best I can deduce from it is "probably should work", but maybe there is some more decisive argument.

Comment: Do you have version of C++ you are targeting as that page spits on C++ version?

Comment: @RichardCritten `jthread` was added in C++20. That's what I'm targeting.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Section 17.13.4 Signal handlers `[support.signal]` states:

> An evaluation is signal-safe unless it includes one of the following:
>
> —(3.1) a call to any standard library function, except for plain lock-free atomic operations and functions explicitly identified as signal-safe; [Note: This implicitly excludes the use of new and delete expressions that rely on a library-provided memory allocator. — end note]

Among the functions marked as signal-safe, I could not find `request_stop`, therefore it is not safe.

But you don't need to use it inside the signal handler. You can simply check two conditions for the potential to stop. Something like this:

```cpp
#include <csignal>
// using std::sig_atomic_t, std::signal
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>


volatile std::sig_atomic_t term_requested;


int main()
{
    std::signal(SIGINT, +[](int sig) {
        term_requested = 1;
    });
    std::jthread thread{[](std::stop_token token) {
        while(! (term_requested || token.stop_requested())) {

        }
        std::cout << "Terminating thread\n";
    }};
    thread.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the signal [handler limitations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) for C++17 onwards, I would use the following reasoning:

> The behavior is undefined if any signal handler performs any of the following:
>
> call to any library function, **except for plain lock-free atomic operations** and the following signal-safe functions (note, in particular, dynamic allocation is not signal-safe):

Then, your function is not on the signal-safe list, and plain lock-free atomic operation is defined as:

> A plain lock-free atomic operation is an invocation of a function f from  or <stdatomic.h>(since C++23), such that:
>
> - f is the function std::atomic_is_lock_free,
> - f is the member function is_lock_free (e.g. std::atomic::is_lock_free()),
> - f is a non-static member function of std::atomic_flag,
> - f is a non-member function, and the first parameter of f has type cv std::atomic_flag*,
> - **f is a non-static member function invoked on an object obj, such that obj.is_lock_free() yields true**, or
> - f is a non-member function, and for every pointer-to-atomic argument arg passed to f, std::atomic_is_lock_free(arg) yields true.

`jthread` is not atomic, so emphasised point doesn't hold, so you cannot call `request_stop` from the signal handler.